# HTML First column wise coloring and aliging center

Tags: html, css

[image]I have Below HTML Table and What I am trying is "Colored Table Header" has to display different color in this example say Blue.
and  Peter, Lois, Joe, Cleveland should color in green (Same as FistName LastName savings format)

Could any help me to achieve. Below is the code i tried so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table align="center">
   <tr>
      <th>Colored Table Header</th>
   </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to add colours only to the headers as you mentioned "Colored Table Header" or the whole column with the header?

Comment: whole column for first column only

Comment: Just added expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>coloured column</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}


th {
background-color:yellow;
    color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="background-color:yellow">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
  <th colspan=3 style="background-color:orange">Coloured Table Header</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
</tr>



</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this out and if you want to make more changes to it but still confused post the comment below.
for more reference visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_col_test).
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: How, Make single Box "Colored Table Header" on top of table?

Comment: so you want to make only one header coloured instead of all three?

Comment: Let me attach sample example in post

Comment: Check it out now i made changes. Run the code snippet so you can see the changes here.

Comment: Made changes again see now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am very new to html. If i copy paste and save as .html extension. Opening in internet explorer and formatting is not coming properly and same thing working fine when i try to run snippet.  anything i am  missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181832/discussion-between-kedar-kodgire-and-dev-ops-ranga).

Answer (score 0):

You could create different classes for your colors and just add them in the class="" attribute

So if we have the class

```
.green{
background: green;
}

<td class="green">name</td>
```

Or we could just use the bgcolor attribute

```
<td bgcolor="#xxxxx"></>td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and colspan (column span) on the `<th>` (table header),
also change the `<td>` to a `<th>` for green colour background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table align="center">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th colspan=3>Colored Table Header</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Peter</th>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Lois</th>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Joe</th>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Cleveland</th>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
thead tr:first-child th {
  text-align:center;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

Html tables codepen: https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/rqGjXE